# GTM - History Change Trigger not tracking Initial PageLoad

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I am using History Change trigger in my GTM TAG to track my page views since mine in Single Page Application(Angular 6). I could see all the page views and its related data are tracked except Initial page load i.e., HomePage.

If I do refresh my home page it is getting tracked. 
Do I need to use different trigger to capture initial page load or Am I missing something here?

Any reference link would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the "all page" trigger to the GTM tag and it will trigger on both history change and page load.